# Greendao can't generate join dao import (ToMany relation)

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao, greendao-generator

Greendao not generating import of ToMany joiner dao. How  can I do this?
I'm creating Book and BookStore, trying save list of books in book store by Custom joiner. After build trying generated Joiner JoinBookStoreWithBookDao not importing in BookStoreDao but exists.

[image: Screenshot]

[Sources](https://github.com/Vakk/greendaotest)

Book.java

```
package com.example.valery.stackoverflowsample.dao;

import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Entity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Id;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Generated;

@Entity
public class Book {

   @Id
   private long id;

   public Book() {
   }
}
```

BookStore.java

```
package com.example.valery.stackoverflowsample.dao;

import com.example.valery.stackoverflowsample.dao.joiner.DaoSession;
import com.example.valery.stackoverflowsample.dao.joiner.JoinBookStoreWithBook;

import org.greenrobot.greendao.DaoException;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Entity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Generated;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Id;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.JoinEntity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.ToMany;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
public class BookStore {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ToMany
    @JoinEntity(
            entity = JoinBookStoreWithBook.class,
            sourceProperty = "bookStoreId",
            targetProperty = "bookId"
    )
    private List<Book> mBooks;
}
```

JoinBookStoreWithBook.java

```
package com.example.valery.stackoverflowsample.dao.joiner;

import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Entity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Id;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Generated;

@Entity
public class JoinBookStoreWithBook {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private long bookId;
    private long bookStoreId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found reason. Joiner should be inside of package for "parent", he can't be in another package.